# String to array in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get arrays from the string. i want the texts as an output, the texts should be in array format.

And i got this error    for line in `txt.readline()`:

> `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'readline'`

```
def de_gutenberger(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        txt = f.read()

        author, title = get_author_and_title(txt)

        # get rid of header & footer
        start_txt = "START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK"
        end_txt   = "END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK"

        start = re.search('('+start_txt+').*?\n', txt)
        start_ind = start.end() if start != None else 0

        end = re.search('('+end_txt+').*?\n', txt)
        end_ind = end.start() if end != None else len(txt)

        word_string = stem_and_stop(nltk.word_tokenize(txt[start_ind:end_ind])) 

        return author, title, word_string


def get_books(folder, files):    
    authors = []
    texts   = []
    titles  = []
    for i, f in enumerate(files):
        print("Number {} of {}".format(i+1, len(files))) 

        author, title, txt = de_gutenberger(folder + f)
        for line in txt.readlines():
            y = [value for value in line.split()]
        texts.append( y )
        authors.append(author)
        titles.append(title)
```

Comment: At a glance my guess is `files` is a list of strings. Before you call `readlines` on it you need to call `open`. That being said, I am not sure what `de_gutenberger` does.

Comment: What does de_gutenberger do?

Answer (score 0):

What does `de_gutenberger` do?  It is returning a tuple, but the 3rd object is NOT a file object, but rather a unicode string.

Try this:

```
def get_books(folder, files): 

    authors = []
    texts   = []
    titles  = []
    for i, f in enumerate(files):
        print("Number {} of {}".format(i+1, len(files))) 
        author, title, txt = de_gutenberger(folder + f)

        y = [value for value in txt.split()]
        texts.append( y )
        authors.append(author)
        titles.append(title)
```

Comment: def de_gutenberger(filename):
 
 #read in 
 with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
  txt = f.read()

 author, title = get_author_and_title(txt)

 # get rid of header & footer
 start_txt = "START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK"
 end_txt   = "END OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK"

 start = re.search('('+start_txt+').*?\n', txt)
 start_ind = start.end() if start != None else 0
  
 end = re.search('('+end_txt+').*?\n', txt)
 end_ind = end.start() if end != None else len(txt)

 word_string = stem_and_stop(nltk.word_tokenize(txt[start_ind:end_ind])) 

 return author, title, word_string

Comment: @naveengullipalli Don't try to put code in comments. Add the new code at the end of the question (don't remove the original code with the problem).

Comment: from de_gutenberger  i am trying to preprocess the data .

Comment: my data is in xml document

Comment: Hi can you please answer me

Comment: your code is working but it execute only for single xml document. but i have multiple documents

Comment: @naveengullipalli it is difficult to help without more information on the specific error.